# When using the webform module, is it possible to get information on the submitter's device (Mac/Win/Android), browser version, etc.?

Tags: webforms

I'm using Webform 3 on Drupal 7.  I have a form on my site for people to report problems with the website itself.  Many of these reports ultimately turn out to be browser- or OS-specific, but often users do not add such information in their initial report.

Is there any way to automatically capture the browser and OS information, etc. in Webform upon submission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears webform allows a default value using %server variables, but only for authenticated users.

> In addition to %get and %post, the following super tokens may be used,
>   though only with logged-in users: %server, %cookie, and %request. For
>   example %server[HTTP_USER_AGENT] or %session[id].

For authenticated users, try adding a User Agent field with a default value of %server[HTTP_USER_AGENT]

If your form submissions come from anonymous users, you may need an alternative way to add the %server tokens.

Other $_SERVER variables documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php